# Using sed to delete lines present in similar file

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed

I have a file listing from an original and a duplicate drive consisting of 985257 lines and 984997 lines respectfully.

As the number of lines do not match I am certain that some of the files have not duplicated.

In order to establish which files are not present I wish to use sed to filter the original file listing by deleting any lines present in the duplicate listing from the source listing.

I had thought about using a match formula in excel but due to the number of lines the program crashes. I thought using this approach in sed would be a viable option.

I have had no success with my approach so far however.

```
 echo "Start"
 # Cat the passed argument which is the duplicate file listing
 for line in $(cat $1)
 do 
   #sed the $line variable over the larger file and remove
   #sed  "${line}/d"  LiveList.csv
   #sed -i "${line}/d"  LiveList.csv
   #sed -i '${line}' 'd'  LiveList.csv
   sed -i "s/'${line}'//" /home/listings/LiveList.csv
 done
```

There is a temporary file which is created and fills to the 103.4mb of the listing file however the listing file itself is not altered at all.

My other concern is that as the listing has been created in windows the '\' character may be escaping the string leading to no matches and therefore no alteration.

```
Example path:
Path,Length,Extension
Jimmy\tail\images\Jimmy\0001\0014\Text\A0\20\A056TH01-01.html,71982,.html
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sort orginal_list.txt duplicate_list.txt | uniq -u
```

Comment: Perfect. It runs really fast as well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind is just using `rsync` to take care of copying the missing files as fast as possible. It really works wonders.

If not, you can first sort both files to identify where they differ. You can use some `paste` trickery to put side by side differences, or even use the `diff` side-by-side output. When files are ordered, I think `diff` finds it easily to identify what lines have been added.

Comment: Seeing as the files arent copying there is a possibility they are flagged as viruses so copying them isnt an option, i need a list. I was running kdiff to do a side by side comparison but with the number of files it is impractical once one 30 files are missing the two files are not aligned at all. A scripted solution will ensure that there is no manual error and give me a nice list of differing files from the two outputs.

Comment: Viruses!?!? Ah, those times long ago when I used windows... Never again :) Anyway, you can increase the window for the search for the diff program for it to try even harder. Also, a scripted solution is going to take you real long, at least with sed and friends. Maybe with perl you'll get better results.